# Is it bad form to shuffle data instead of pointers to it?

Tags: c, pointers

This isn't actually a homework question per se, just a question that keeps nagging me as I do my homework. My book sometimes gives an exercise about rearranging data, and will explicitly say to do it by changing only pointers, not moving the data (for example, in a linked list making use of a "node" struct with a data field and a next/pointer field, only change the next field).

Is it bad form to move data instead? Sometimes it seems to make more sense (either for efficiency or clarity) to move the data from one struct to another instead of changing pointers around, and I guess I'm just wondering if there's a good reason to avoid doing that, or if the textbook is imposing that constraint to more effectively direct my learning.

Thanks for any thoughts. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: What example are you thinking of when you say copying the data is more efficient than copying a pointer?

Comment: Well, in some of my assignments, the only data I'm storing is an int. So since an int is the same size as a pointer, swapping two ints instead of swapping four pointers (say in a doubly-linked list) would be more efficient (I know, I know, constant amount of work, it's so marginal of an benefit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 3 reasons:

**Genericness / Maintainability**:

If you can get your algorithm to work by modifying pointers only, then it will always work regardless of what kind of data you put in your "node".

If you do it by modifying data, then your algorithm will be married to your data structure, and may not work if you change your data structure.

**Efficiency**:

Further, you mention efficiency, and you will be hard-pressed to find a more efficient operation than copying a pointer, which is just an integer, typically already the size of a machine word.

**Safety**:

And further still, the pointer-manipulation route will not cause confusion with other code which has its own pointers to your data, as @caf points out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  It generally makes sense to move the smaller thing, so if the data being shuffled is larger than a pointer (which is usually the case), then it makes more sense to shuffle pointers rather than data.

In addition, if other code might have retained pointers to the data, then it wouldn't expect the data to be changed from underneath, so this again points towards shuffling pointers rather than data.

Comment: It's mostly that second one.  All standard node-based containers' iterators are _not_ invalidated by inserts/erases.  Rearranging only the pointers is how it pulls that off.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling pointers or indexes is done when copying or moving the actual objects is difficult or inefficient. There's nothing wrong with shuffing the objects themselves if that's more convenient.

In fact by eliminating the pointers you eliminate a whole bunch of potential problems that you get with pointers, such as whether and when and how to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Moving data takes more time and depending on the nature of your data it may also don't like relocations (like the structure containing pointers into itself for whatever reasons).

Answer (score 0):

If you have pointers, I assume they exist in the dynamic memory...
In other words, they just exist... So why bother changing the data from one to another, reallocating if necessary?

Usually, the purpose of a list is to have values from everywhere, from a memory perspective, into a continuous list.

With such a structure, you can re-arrange and re-order the list, without having to move the data.

You've to to understand that moving data implies reading and writing into memory (not speaking about reallocation).

It's resource consuming... So re-ordering only the addresses is a lot more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data. If you're just moving around `int`s or `char`s, it would be no more expensive to shuffle the data than the pointer. However, once you pass a certain size or complexity, you start to lose efficiency quickly. Moving objects by pointer will work for any contained data, so getting used to using pointers, even on the toy structs that are used in your assignments, will help you handle those large, complex objects without.

It is especially idiomatic to handle things by pointer when dealing with something like a linked list. The whole point of the linked list is that the Node part can be as large or complex as you like, and the semantics of shuffling, sorting, inserting, or removing nodes all stay the same. This is the key to templated containers in C++ (which I know is not the primary target of this question). C++ also encourages you to consider and limit the number of times you shuffle things by data, because that involves calling a copy constructor on each object each time you move it. This doesn't work well with many C++ idioms, such as RAII, which makes a constructor a rather expensive but very useful operation.